# How do I remove an unwanted texture that keeps showing up in Object mode?

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

I really want to know how to remove or erase this little bit of unwanted texture from Object mode as I've already got a texture to go above it. It gets covered up when I put it in texture paint but as soon as I return to object mode (and view on Texture) it comes back.

It also comes back on top of the actual textures when I output this character into the game. Please help.

Comment: Try unhiding everything in Edit mode and see if there's a tri assigned to some orange like texture. Make  sure also to select all in Edit mode and assign selection to desired texture by choosing it in the UV editor. Include some information about how do you export your character into the game, what settings, what format, what game engine etc